# "he shall not go out anymore" Rev 3:12

Tags: revelation

What is the significance behind this simple statement? In this context we are now granted eternal life. Presently, we can barely imagine what places we will go to and accomplish forever. We surely cannot be limited to a 'physical place', not being 'physical' ourselves.

> The one overcoming, I will make him a pillar in the temple of My God, and **he shall not go out anymore**. And I will write upon him the name of My God, and the name of the city of My God, the new Jerusalem coming down out of heaven from My God, and My new name. Rev 3:12

What are we not going out from?
Why are we not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NIV Revelation 3:

> 7 “To the angel of the church in **Philadelphia** write:
> ...
> 11 I am coming soon. Hold on to what you have, so that no one will take your crown. 12 The one who is victorious I will make a **pillar** in the temple of my God. Never again will they leave it.

The victorious believer is likened to a pillar in the temple of God. In this imagery, he will never fall or go astray again. In this sense, he shall not go out anymore.
This is not meant to limit his mobility but to emphasize his stability that will not be shaken.

[Vincent](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/revelation/3-12.htm) contrasts this image with a

> local reference to the frequent earthquakes from which **Philadelphia** had suffered, and which had shaken its temples. Strabo says: "And Philadelphia has not even its walls unimpaired, but daily they are shaken in some way, and gaps are made in them."

1 Peter 2:5 uses a similar image:

> you also, like **living stones**, are being built into a spiritual house to be a holy priesthood, offering spiritual sacrifices acceptable to God through Jesus Christ.

Answer (score 1):

Rev 3:12 contains the metaphor of a person being a pillar in the temple of God.

> The one who overcomes I will make a pillar in the temple of My God,
> and he will never again leave it. ...

That is, the person is a permanent pillar, not a temporary pillar in the temple of God.

The Apostle Paul, uses exactly the same metaphor in 1 Cor 3:16 where we read:

> Do you not know that you yourselves are God’s temple, and that God’s
> Spirit dwells in you?

Again, as part of the temple/church of God, we are permanently part of God's people, not temporarily.  Leaving God's temple (in the metaphoric sense) is to leave the presence of God and cease to be part of God's people.

Thus, Rev 3:12 states a simple truth about the overcomers in the letter to the Philadelphians - they are always part of God's people and the temple/church of God.

Answer (score 0):

It is not excluded that this *going out* can refer to the ***outer darkness*** of [Matthew 8:12](https://biblehub.com/matthew/8-12.htm), [22:13](https://biblehub.com/matthew/22-13.htm), [25:30](https://biblehub.com/matthew/25-30.htm).

But here is what [Matthew Henry](https://www.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/matthew-henry-complete/revelation/3.html) says on this verse:

> Christ promises a glorious reward to the victorious believer: he shall
> be a monumental pillar in the temple of God; not a pillar to support
> the temple (heaven needs no such props), but *a monument of the free
> and powerful grace of God*, *a monument that shall never be defaced
> **nor removed***, as many stately pillars erected in honour to the Roman emperors and generals have been.